# iOS Swift App, Openweather API

Tags: ios, api, swift3

I'm making a weather app using OpenweatherAPI. I download data from web, but when I want to pass it to another class it show as nil. Here is the code:

So that's the class I'm getting data from the API

```
var currentTemp: Double {
    if _currentTemp == nil {
        _currentTemp = 120.0
    }
    return _currentTemp
}

func downloadWeatherDetails(completed: @escaping DownloadComplete) {
    Alamofire.request(CURRENT_WEATHER_URL).responseJSON { response in
        let result = response.result

        if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
            if let main = dict["main"] as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                if let currentTemperature = main["temp"] as? double_t {

                    let kelvinToCelsiusPreDivision = (currentTemperature - 273.15)
                    let kelvinToCelsius = Double(round((10 * kelvinToCelsiusPreDivision) / 10))

                    self._currentTemp = kelvinToCelsius
                    print(self._currentTemp)
                }
            }
        }
        completed()  
} }
```

And the mainVC - ViewController:

```
func updateMainUI() {
    currentTempLabel.text = "\(currentWeather.currentTemp)"
}
```

I'm of course calling updateMainUI in ViewDidLoad, but IMHO I think the method that updates UI is probably called before getting the data from the JSON.

The Label on the App shows 120 - so it is considered as nil...
Sorry about parenthesis if there is something wrong.
Thanks for help in advice :)

EDIT:

Ohh and I forgot to add.. The data from API is perfectly fine, so the call to API is working :)

Comment: You need to update the UI again after the `completion` handler has been called, it's only at that point the data will be available.

Answer (score 0):

// I Hope that helps

```
func downloadWeatherDetails(completed: @escaping DownloadComplete) {
    //Download Current Weather Data
    Alamofire.request(CURRENT_WEATHER_URL).responseJSON { response in
        let result = response.result

        if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

            if let main = dict["main"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

                if let currentTemperature = main["temp"] as? Double {

                    let kelvinToFarenheitPreDivision = (currentTemperature * (9/5) - 459.67)

                    let kelvinToFarenheit = Double(round(10 * kelvinToFarenheitPreDivision/10))

                    self._currentTemp = kelvinToFarenheit
                    print(self._currentTemp)
                }
            }
        }
        completed()
    }
}
```